# What's the meaning of 'lawn supplies'?

Tags: meaning

What's the meaning of **lawn supplies**?

Please explain in detail.

I encountered this sentence in TOEIC questions.

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. Context is essential to meaning; a *lawn* means something different to a gardener, a textile manufacturer, and a microbiologist. While it's most likely to be the first meaning here, you should still [edit] the post to state where you encountered this phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything pertaining to the maintenance of a lawn(grass). So, **lawn mower, fertilizer, fertilizer spreader, sprinklers, hoses, trimmers/edgers, insecticide etc**. That really is all there is to it! A Google search of this term will provide you with an expansive list.

[image: Google Search Results]

Comment: What do you mean by 'That really is all there is to it'? I have hard time analyzing this sentence..

Comment: The term 'lawn supplies' is considered a word that explains it's self. So "that's really all there is to it!" Means "it's not more complex than that!"

Comment: -1 for "A Google search of this term will provide you with an expansive list." I just Googled this term, and I got a list of businesses that sell lawn supplies, nothing about the term itself. Moreover, Googling a term is something that an OP should do even before the question is asked (and, preferably, telling us what they found), not something recommended in an answer.

Comment: I don't know what version of Google you're using but.. https://imgur.com/a/qsYaW

Comment: Make that image a little smaller and put it in your answer, and I'll happily delete my comment and reverse my downvote. My result looked like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aBcA.png).